# How to get custom enviornment variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for a way to get a list of my custom variables in Jenkins and the values set in them.
Is there some url request I can use?

Comment: Custom variables as in what? Variables which you can pass to some command?

Comment: What kind of vars? Env vars? During build execution? Please, specify.

Comment: The variables that Jenkins allows us to set in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties.
I have a few of these key value pairs set and I need to access them from outside jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath, depth and tree parameters, for example>

http://jenkins.example.com/job/YOURJOBNAME/api/json?xpath=/hudson/job[1]/build[1]/action[1]/parameter&depth=3&tree=name,description,allBuilds[actions[parameters[name,value]],number,building,url,duration,fullDisplayName,timestamp,result],inQueue,queueItem[actions[parameters[name,value]]]&pretty

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Windows system environment variables than run batch command **set** and read the output or using Groovy script:

```html
def env = System.getenv()
String variable= env['your_var']
```